# Error when trying to run Java related commands on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, clojure

For example, if I do `java -version` I get:

```
Error: dl failure on line 542
Error: failed /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib, because dlopen(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib: code signature invalid for '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib'
```

What am I to do? I have JDK installed:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (1):
    14, x86_64: "Java SE 14"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home
```

and I've intalled JRE as well though I get the error if I try to invoke java.

My Mac Details:

```
OS X Yosemite
Version 10.10.5 (14F27)
Processor 2.66 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
```

MacBook Pro (15-inch, Mid 2009)

Answer (score 2):

That is a fairly old version of OS X with a brand spanking new version of the JDK, which might not have been built in a way intended to be run on that old of a version of OS X.  I'd recommend trying out AdoptOpenJDK 8 or 11, and see if things work better there.