# How do I install Java correctly? Because when I install it and go to a terminal, it gives me an error message, knowing that I have a MacBook Pro

Tags: java, macos

```sh
MBP-de-mac:~ mac$ java -version
Error: dl failure on line 558
Error: failed /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib, because dlopen(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib, 10): no suitable image found.
Did find: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib: code signature invalid for '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib'
```

Comment: I only find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60868198/error-when-trying-to-run-java-related-commands-on-macos). Can you try to reinstall java?

Comment: brew install java?